# Bash script being too resource intensive

Tags: bash, scripting, resources

I wrote a script in bash that basically takes a wordlist file and checks every line it contains against another list, and outputs the non-matching lines to "uniques.txt". I found though, that this is VERY resource intensive, and takes a lot of time. As i am not a computer scientist or engineer, i don't really know what is going on in the metal.. I heard "C" was a great language because of this issue... Heres a portion of the code:

```
if [[ "$1" =~ ^\-i(.*)+$ ]]; then
    echo "[*] Testing lines in \""$2"\" against \""$3"\"..."
    for string in $(cat "$2"); do
        if ! cat "$3" | grep -x "$string" &>/dev/null; then
            echo "$string" >> uniques.txt
        fi
    done
fi
```

A sample use of this script would be: "$script" -i "$wordlist" "$wordlist_to check_against". 
The contents of the files would be strings with no spaces in between, one per line, as in:

```
johnson
peter
newyork
amsterdam
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regex you match $1 against makes no sense. The first parameter should start with `-i` followed by anything (including an empty string) repeated at least once. It's identical to `^-i`, i.e. it starts with `-i`.

`"in \""$2"\"` is strange. It prints `$2` unquoted, i.e. it can show the name wrong if it contains whitespace (e.g. file `a  b` will be shown as `a b`).

`in $(cat` means the words are read from file one by one, i.e. if there is more than one word per line in $2, they will be matched separately.

You can use `grep -f` to read the patterns from a file and avoid the loops that cause the slowness:

```
#! /bin/bash
if [[ $1 =~ ^-i ]]; then
    echo "[*] Testing lines in \"$2\" against \"$3\"..."
    grep -vxf "$2" "$3"
fi
```

Comment: Thank you for the heads up. I escaped the quotes to actually show them during the script run. When i put it only around the variable, wouldn't it only consider it a string?

Comment: My snippet shows how to show them during script run while still keeping the variables inside double quotes.

Comment: "grep -vxf" didn't work though, it prints lots of:                                                 "grep: $file (not checked):$line: Unmatched [ or [^"

Comment: Sounds like your patterns contain special characters. How do you want them to match? Maybe you need to add `-F`, too?

Comment: Ok, it worked! Just had to add -F. Thank you for the patience!